# How to apply patch to Richfaces 4.0.0.Final

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces, patch

I found a bug in Richfaces 4.x. I need to change Autocomplete.js of Richfaces 4.

I googled about it but i didnt find a satisfying solution.

Can anyone explain to me how to apply patch Richafaces 4.x?

Thank you in advance

Comment: did you reported the bug?

Comment: It was reported.It is fixed in Richfaces 4.3.0.M2.But I dont want to upgrade my Richaces version to 4.3.0. So I want to apply patch to Richfaces 4.0.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fork it or upload it in `Github` as patched(I assumed that you patched it) and import the patched library via maven to your project.

I guess, Maven does not support loading from github natively. But you can use a plugin to download it from github.